# GCP API - tagamanger REST API - powershell - domain verfication

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-platform, google-tag-manager

I have been trying to automate the addition of users to many tagmanager accounts through powershell.

I have manged to get myself through oauth setup, got the access token and refresh token.

However when I go to try and list all the accounts, I get a 403 response, when I look at this in the play ground its working.

Now when I look at GCP, I can see the consent page want to do some domain verification, as I have apparently added sensitive scopes. However I am not building a app, I am just running the scripts as a management/administrative exercise. So I am not sure what i can as the consent form wants me to supply domains, home pages, etc.

Anyone have any ideas?

Regards
Allan

Comment: Don't use user credentials, use Google Cloud service accounts. https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

As John said is recommended to use a Service Accounts for non-human users:
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/#principals

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/api/v2/authorization

Did you fix it?